# Updating values based on removed characters from string

Tags: python, string, pandas, list

I am working with a dataset in which I want to extract a certain substring from a sequence.

One of my columns contains indexes of characters within the sequence which are referenced (e.g.) `[45,45,D]` meaning that the character at the 45th position belongs to class D and indicates that the characters at position 1 to 44 are not referenced, and I have therefore removed them.

Once the characters at those positions have been removed, I want to update the numbers in that column to indicate (e.g) `[1,1,D]` as now the 45th position is now referencing the first position.

I am finding this difficult, as for example, for the another sequence, `[84,115,S]` So the characters at position 84 to 115 belongs to class S. The next pair of values is `[151, 152, 'C']` 
Therefore, the characters at position 116 to 150 have been removed, and `[151, 152, 'C']` must be updated to `[116, 117,S]`. 
The subsequent numbers in the list must also be updated (i.e.) the next number will be [118,..] instead of [153,...].

I have provided a sample of the original sequence, the shortened sequence and the referenced character positions.

**Original Sequence**: MSEVTRSLLQRWGASLRRGADFDSWGQLVEAIDEYQILARHLQKEAQAQHNNSEFTEEQKKTIGKIATCLELRSAALQSTQSQEEFKLEDLKKLEPILKNILTYNKEFPFDVQPIPLRRILAPGEEENLEFEEDEEGGAGAGPPDSFSARVPGTLLPRLPSEPGMTLLTIRIEKIGLKDAGQCIDPYITVSVKDLNGIDLTPVQDTPVASRKEDTYVHFNVDIELQKHVERLTKGAAIFFEFKHYKPKKRFTSTKCFAFMEMDEIKPGPIVIELYKKPTDFKRKKLQLLTKKPLYLHLHQSLHKE

**Shortened Sequence**: MSEVTRSLLQRWGASLRRGADFDSWGQLVEAIDEYQILARHLQKEAQAQHNNSEFTEEQKKTIGKIATCLELRSAALQSTQSQEEFKLEDLKKLEPILKNILTYNKEFPFDVQPIVPGTLLPRLPSEPGMTLLTIRIEKIGLKDAGQCIDPYITVSVKDLNGIDLTPVQDTPVASRKEDTYVHFNVDIELQKHVERLTKGAAIFFEFKHYKPKKRFTSTKCFAFMEMDEIKPGPIVIELYKKPTDFKRKKLQLLTKKPLYLHLHQSLHKE

**Referenced character positions**: `[[1, 3, 'C'], [4, 48, 'S'], [49, 54, 'C'], [55, 79, 'S'], [80, 83, 'C'], [84, 115, 'S'], [151, 152, 'C'], [153, 304, 'S'], [305, 305, 'D']]`

My current approach is as follows:

Looking at the two entries: `[84, 115, 'S']` and `[151, 152, 'C']`
Say:
A = 115 and B = 151.
The difference between these two numbers is 36, therefore if I subtract 35 from each of the subsequent numbers after 151, it will give me the correct positioning of the class: i.e. [116, 117, ‘C’]. I need to do this for every place where some of the sequence has been removed.

So I compare every 2nd number in the first [] with the first number of the next [] and if this difference is > 1, then the index has to be updated.

I also have the case where part of the sequence is removed from the start of the sequence also.

I have tried this by doing as follows:

Where "shortenedlist1" is a list of lists which contain the numbers referring to the character positions: (i.e.) `[[45, 45, 46, 49, 50, 66, 67, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109, 120, 121, 121, 122, 123, 124, 140, 141, 149, 150, 176, 177, 178, 179, 181, 182, 194, 195, 213, 214, 217], [1, 1, 2, 143, 144, 145], [1, 145], [24, 29, 30, 91, 92, 92], [22, 24, 25, 38, 39, 55, 56, 348]...`

```
mylist = []
i=0
j=0

for sublist in shortened_list1:
    while j < len(shortened_list1):
        A = sublist[0]
        Y = sublist[i+1]
        Z = sublist[j+2]

        if A != 0:
            sublist = [x - (A-1) for x in sublist]
            mylist.append(sublist)
        elif (Z-Y) >1:
            sublist = [x - (Z-Y-1) for x in sublist]
            mylist.append(sublist)

mylist
```

This returns the correct result for the first sublist. But does not work for subsequent sublists, or for cases when the portion of the sequence has been removed from the middle.

Comment: What are 'i' and 'j'? They don't change at all.

Comment: i is the second number of the first [ ] and j is the first number of the second [ ]. For example, in [84, 115, 'S'] and [151, 152, 'C'], i = 115 and j = 151. I wanted to compare these numbers, and if the difference > 1, then I wanted to update the value of j and subsequent values, as it would indicate that there is missing position referencing between these numbers. So for example, 151 would be reduced to 116 as there is a difference of 35 between i and j.

Comment: ^^ i and j are the positions of those numbers in the shortenedlist1. Sorry couldn't edit above comment to clarify. So i and j would then be incremented by 2, to refer to the next two numbers for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question right, this should extract the correct subsequence and update the intervals.

```
seq = "MSEVTRSLLQRWGASLRRGADFDSWGQLVEAIDEYQILARHLQKEAQAQHNNSEFTEEQKKTIGKIATCLELRSAALQSTQSQEEFKLEDLKKLEPILKNILTYNKEFPFDVQPIPLRRILAPGEEENLEFEEDEEGGAGAGPPDSFSARVPGTLLPRLPSEPGMTLLTIRIEKIGLKDAGQCIDPYITVSVKDLNGIDLTPVQDTPVASRKEDTYVHFNVDIELQKHVERLTKGAAIFFEFKHYKPKKRFTSTKCFAFMEMDEIKPGPIVIELYKKPTDFKRKKLQLLTKKPLYLHLHQSLHKE"

intervals = [[1, 3, 'C'], [4, 48, 'S'], [49, 54, 'C'], [55, 79, 'S'], [80, 83, 'C'], [84, 115, 'S'], [151, 152, 'C'], [153, 304, 'S'], [305, 305, 'D']]

substrings = []

for i in intervals:
    #Takes the substring between the ranges
    substrings.append( seq[i[0]-1 : i[1]] )

final = ""
#Concatinates all of the substrings
for s in substrings:
    final += s

curInd = 1
#Adjusts the intervals
for i in range(len(intervals)):
    section = intervals[i]
    if section[0] != curInd: #If the interval is not correct
        dif = section[0] - curInd
        section[0]-=dif #Adjusts both sides
        section[1]-=dif
    curInd = section[1]+1 #update current ind
```

From here, you should have the extracted substring as `final`

Comment: If the results are not what you wanted, please leave a comment

Comment: I already have the shortened sequences, so all i want to do is update the intervals!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'cumsum' and 'shift':

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, 'C'], [4, 48, 'S'], [49, 54, 'C'], [55, 79, 'S'], [80, 83, 'C'], [84, 115, 'S'], [151, 152,'C'], [153, 304, 'S'], [305, 305, 'D']],columns=["start","stop","cls"])

    start  stop cls
0      1     3   C
1      4    48   S
2     49    54   C
3     55    79   S
4     80    83   C
5     84   115   S
6    151   152   C
7    153   304   S
8    305   305   D

df["length"]=df.stop.sub(df.start).add(1)
df["new_start"]=df.length.cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)
df["new_stop"]=df.new_start.add(df.length).sub(1)

rslt= df.reindex(columns=["new_start","new_stop","cls"]).agg(list,axis=1).to_list()

[[0, 2, 'C'],
 [3, 47, 'S'],
 [48, 53, 'C'],
 [54, 78, 'S'],
 [79, 82, 'C'],
 [83, 114, 'S'],
 [115, 116, 'C'],
 [117, 268, 'S'],
 [269, 269, 'D']]
```

Comment: This seems straightforward when there is one set of intervals. Whereas I have over 5000 sequences. How would I be able to keep track of each sublist within the data frame? As outlined above, the intervals are contained within a sublist of a list, if I add all these to the data frame, how can I split it up again into the sublists so I know which sequence is being referenced?

Comment: Okay, so I know how to deal with the rest of the sequences. But I am experiencing an issue when I want to apply it to the whole thing: How do I get the new_start and the new_stop to start again once the first set of intervals for the first sequence is done? E.g. in the example you've given, how do I get it to reset to 1 after 269 has been reached?